# How do I SELECT from a table with a JOIN with multiple matching values?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following simple query that works just fine when there is one keyword to match:

```
SELECT gc.id, gc.name 
FROM gift_card AS gc
JOIN keyword ON gc.id = keyword.gc_id 
WHERE keyword = 'mini'
GROUP BY gc.id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

What I want to do is find the `id`'s that **match at least two of the keywords** I provide. I thought just adding a simple `AND` would work but I get blank results.

```
SELECT gc.id, gc.name 
FROM gift_card AS gc
JOIN keyword ON gc.id = keyword.gc_id 
WHERE keyword = 'mini'
AND keyword = '2012'
GROUP BY gc.id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Obviously SQL is not my strong suit so I am looking for some help one what I am doing wrong here.

Here are my table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `gift_card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `keyword` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dupes_UNIQUE` (`gc_id`,`keyword`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=477 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Your first query won't work because you have `gc.name` in the column list but not in the `GROUP BY` (that error also made it in your second query). Maybe that accidentally sneaked in before you copied it here. But you wouldn't need it anyway, if your goal is only the retrieval of the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `and` does not work.  A column cannot have two different values in one row.

Instead, `or` . . . and a bit more logic:

```
SELECT gc.id, gc.name 
FROM gift_card gc JOIN
     keyword k
     ON gc.id = k.gc_id 
WHERE k.keyword IN ('mini', '2012')
GROUP BY gc.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2  -- both match
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

It is a good idea to qualify *all* column names in a query that has more than one table reference.